# Why is int(x-1) == x True in Python 3.7 with some values of x?

Tags: python

In Python 3.7     `int(x-1) == x` is   `True`  for `x = 5e+17`
Why is this so and how do I prevent this bug?

To reproduce, paste this into your Python console:

```
int(5e+17-1) == 5e+17
>True
```

(I am using `int` because x is the result of a division and I need to parse it as int.)

Comment: If you expand ```5e+17``` then it will return ```False``` -> ```(500000000000000000 - 1) == 5e17 [OUT] False```

Comment: In python, 5e17 is a floating point value and has a limited precision. You can try parsing to int first: `int(5e17)-1 == int(5e17)` is `False`.

Comment: it is a decimal approximation failure

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's start by establishing that `5 == 5.0` is `True` even though `5` is an `int` and `5.0` is a `float`. This is by design.

If we keep that in mind, then we can also accept that `int(5e+17) == 5e+17` is `True`.

Finally, we see that `int(5e+17) == int(5e+17-1)` is also `True` because of [precision](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) errors (Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga for the link).

Now it is clear why `int(5e+17-1) == 5e+17` is `True`.

This can be solved by using [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html) but be sure to initialize it with a string:

```
from decimal import Decimal

Decimal('5e+17') - 1 ==  Decimal('5e+17')

# False
```

Comment: How to prevent it? I mean how to force the precision to be correct?

Comment: I don't understand the precision thing

Comment: Not OP but I was just playing around with this in my console, good answer.  Is there a part in the documentation that talks about this precision?  It would be helpful to understand it further.

Comment: @DeepSpace `Decimal` should help, but you can't start by feeding it an imprecise `float`, you have to give it a `str`

Comment: @Carlos Python `float` objects represent fixed-size (usually 64-bit) floating point numbers, `int` objects on the other hand have arbitrary size. So see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Correct!

Comment: @TSR See the updated answer for a solution using `Decimal`

Comment: thanks, I now have worked out float addition problem -  float(Decimal('0.1')  + Decimal('0.2')) == 0.3  -> true

Answer (score 3):

Python `float` is stored as a [double-precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) number.  They only have 53 bits of precision, so integers larger than 2<sup>53</sup> stored as floats begin to lose precision.  Here's a clear example of how large numbers begin to lose precision:

```
>>> x = float(2**53-10)
>>> x
9007199254740982.0
>>> for i in range(20):
...   print(x+i)
...
9007199254740982.0
9007199254740983.0
9007199254740984.0
9007199254740985.0
9007199254740986.0
9007199254740987.0
9007199254740988.0
9007199254740989.0
9007199254740990.0
9007199254740991.0  <--- 2**53-1
9007199254740992.0  <--- 2**53
9007199254740992.0  <--- NOT 2**53+1
9007199254740994.0  <--- 2**53+2
9007199254740996.0
9007199254740996.0
9007199254740996.0
9007199254740998.0
9007199254741000.0
9007199254741000.0
9007199254741000.0
```

The above number is approximately 9e+15, so your 1e+17 number is well into loss of precision.  **You have to add/subtract 16 from floats that large to expect a change in stored value**:

```
>>> x = 1e17
>>> for i in range(20):
...  print(f'{x+i:.1f}')
...
100000000000000000.0
100000000000000000.0
100000000000000000.0
100000000000000000.0
100000000000000000.0
100000000000000000.0
100000000000000000.0
100000000000000000.0
100000000000000000.0
100000000000000016.0
100000000000000016.0
100000000000000016.0
100000000000000016.0
100000000000000016.0
100000000000000016.0
100000000000000016.0
100000000000000016.0
100000000000000016.0
100000000000000016.0
100000000000000016.0
```

Python has functions to convert to and from an exact binary floating point value.  The 1 before and 13 hexadecimal digits after the decimal indicate the 53-bit value:

```
>>> (1e17).hex()
'0x1.6345785d8a000p+56'
>>> print(f"{float.fromhex('0x1.6345785d8a000p56'):.1f}")
100000000000000000.0
```

Adding one to the 53-bit value:

```
>>> print(f"{float.fromhex('0x1.6345785d8a001p56'):.1f}")
100000000000000016.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`5e+17` is a [floating point literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-floatnumber), not an integer literal.

In CPython, `float` type is a double precision float which is [64-bit IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) in most current CPUs. This means you only have 53 bits to represent the digits (about 16 decimal digits). Extra digits will be lost. For example:

```
>>> 111111111111111119.0 == 111111111111111118.0
True
>>> 0.111111111111111119 == 0.111111111111111118
True
```

While:

```
>>> 111111111111111119 == 111111111111111118
False
```

OTH, you can use integers; While 64-bit integers can only represent about 19 decimal digits, Python will automatically create unlimited precision integer objects instead of machine-size integers when required.

```py
>>> 5*10**17-1
499999999999999999

>>> 5*10**70 -1
49999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999

>>> a = 5*10**100 
>>> a
50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>>> a-1 == a
False
```

Since you want to process the result as int, you can convert it to an integer after the division  before further processing to preserve precision:

```
>>> int(5e+17)-1 == 5 * 10**17
False
```